# How to convert RDF graph to .dot format?

Tags: rdf, dot, rdflib

I have RDF graph g:

```
ex1:Netherlands a ex1:Country ;
    ex1:hasCapital ex1:Amsterdam ;
    ex1:hasName "The Netherlands" ;
    ex1:neighbours ex1:Belgium .
```

I need to convert this to a .dot graph:

```
dot = graphviz.Digraph(strict=True, graph_attr={"dpi":"50"})  # adjust dpi to scale graph
for s,p,o in g:
    pass
```

How do I get to this?